# How to stream AKS pod logs into Eventhubs?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is there any solution to send AKS pod logs into Eventhub automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain this is not possible directly (because AKS can only stream to OMS), but [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/stream-monitoring-data-event-hubs) outlines some principles. So you can create a function\logic app to do that for you.